# Mail (nodemailer/maigun-js) does not send from Node

Tags: node.js, azure, virtual-machine, mailgun, nodemailer

For a complete registration confirmation, I am trying to send a confirmation mail to the user that is about to sing up. I am using node.js and, for mail sending, I have tried both [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) and [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js). Everything works great with either nodemailer/mailgun when testing on **localhost**, emails are send flawlessly. But as soon as I **deploy** it (on an **azure virtual machine** with ubuntu) the email **does not send**. I have tried many different approaches to this but none succeed: all have the same behavior: mail gets sent when on localhost but nothing happens when ran from live server, with **the same code**, from each specific documentation. What could be blocking the server from sending emails?

> One more important clue: on server, using the **command line** with [swaks](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api) the mail is sent **successfully**.
>   Also a standalone js file with the code for email sending works from the server.

```
var API_KEY = 'MY_API_KEY';
var DOMAIN = 'MY_DOMAIN_NAME';
var HOST = 'MY_EU_HOST';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: API_KEY, domain: DOMAIN, host: HOST});

const data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'foo@example.com',
  subject: 'Hello',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

UPDATED: the only way I got this to work was by using [mailgun.js](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js) and NOT [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js). The question remains, as isolating the send mail node script works for mailgun-js also. The thing is that **mailgun.js** works in the project, **mailgun-js** does NOT. It is very unclear to me why this happens and would still apreaciate any explination about the differences bettween the two. To enforce the mystery, [mailgun official documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#sending-via-api) have in their examples `require('mailgun-js')` and **NOT** `require('mailgun.js')`

Answer (score 0):

You're right, if you are using 3rd party email service , it has nothing to do with port 25 of Azure VMs.

It should use the same protocol no matter you call your email function in a sample js or via API. Based on your code , I coded a sample API which is used for sending emails to my mail box and I host the API on Azure Linux (ubuntu 18.04) VM :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/email', function (req, res) {

    const mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
    const DOMAIN = "sandbox3b95c6dff0fb4b4a8aaa3c59a7eb9abc.mailgun.org";
    const mg = mailgun({apiKey: "<key here>", domain: DOMAIN});
    const data = {
        from: "Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox3b95c6dff0fb4b4a8aaa3c59a7eb9abc.mailgun.org>",
        to: "<my email address>",
        subject: "Hello",
        text: "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"
    };
    mg.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });


   res.end("email has been sent!!!");
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

as you can see , my node server listening 8081 port , so I enabled 8081 port on my VM network security group(you can consider it as an Azure platform level firewall) : 
[image]
Call the API directly using get method :
[image]
Azure VM side received the request : 
[image]
Received the email successfully: 
[image]

Seems everything works as excepted , hope it helps .

Comment: Hi @CezarCobuz, anything else I can assist with ?

Comment: Created a simple standalone js file and ran it from the live server. The script has the same code for send email but with mocked data, it works perfectly from the server, it sends email, so I am assuming port 25 is not the problem in this case.

Comment: [@Stanley Gong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189459/stanley-gong) I don't see how, but could it be a different protocol if I run a script directly from server vs any users calls an api that fires the same(-ish) script?

Comment: Hi @CezarCobuz, I did some test for you and updated my answer , have a check pls .

Comment: the only way I got this to work was by using [mailgun.js](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-js) and NOT [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js). The question remains, as isolating the send mail node script words for mailgun-js also. The thing is that **mailgun.js** works in the project, **mailgun-js** does NOT.

Comment: [@Stanley Gang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10189459/stanley-gong) I updated the question with the only thing that worked and explained why this is still unclear for me.

Comment: Hi @CezarCobuz , I tried both mailgun.js and mailgun-js for you and all of them works for me . If you can use them to send emails in an isolate project, but not works in your main project, could you pls share your main project code here ? If not I am afraid I cant dig out the root reason .